# In Orchard how do I create a query that includes an associated Part?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I'm working in a new module for an orchard project.  We've build a Company Part which is associated with an Address Part.  What I'm eventually trying to get to is allowing users to enter various search criteria via the ui (non-admin interface), perform a search against all companies and return any matching results.

Where I'm struggling is how to build the query which allows me to include info from the associated address.  So far I've only been able to successfully return results based on the CompanyPartRecord as opposed to the CompanyPart. The CompanyPartRecord obviously only contains the Address_Id of the associated AddressPart.

In essence I'm trying to get to something like this which will return an enumerable or list of companies which match the entered search criteria.  There are more search options beyond zip so I'm looking for an extensible solution.

```
var query = _companyRepository.Table.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Zip))
        query = query.Where(c => c.Address.Zip == Zip);

var queryResult = query.ToList();
```

I've tried using both an IRepository (shown above) and with IContentManager such as the following:

```
var query = _contentManager.Query<CompanyPart, CompanyPartRecord>();
//var query = _contentManager.Query<CompanyPart>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Zip))
    query = query.Where(c => c.Address.Zip == Zip);

var queryResult = query.ToList();
```

Here's the actual Company and Address (Parts and Records):

```
public class CompanyPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
   {
      public virtual string Name { get; set; }
      public virtual string Description { get; set; }
      public virtual int Address_Id { get; set; }
      public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
      public virtual string OtherInformation { get; set; }
      public virtual string Website { get; set; }
      public virtual bool Inactive { get; set; }

      // Keywords - Taxonomy
      // Logo - associated part
      // HasMissingData - derived
      // NumberOfEmployees - associated part
   }

   public class CompanyPart : ContentPart<CompanyPartRecord>, ITitleAspect
   {
      internal readonly LazyField<AddressPart> AddressField = new LazyField<AddressPart>();

      public string Name
      {
         get { return Record.Name; }
         set { Record.Name = value; }
      }

      public string Description
      {
         get { return Record.Description; }
         set { Record.Description = value; }
      }

      public AddressPart Address
      {
         get { return AddressField.Value; }
         set { AddressField.Value = value; }
      }

      public string Phone
      {
         get { return Record.Phone; }
         set { Record.Phone = value; }
      }

      public string OtherInformation
      {
         get { return Record.OtherInformation; }
         set { Record.OtherInformation = value; }
      }

      public string Website
      {
         get { return Record.Website; }
         set { Record.Website = value; }
      }

      public bool Inactive
      {
         get { return Record.Inactive; }
         set { Record.Inactive = value; }
      }

      public string Title
      {
         get { return Name; }
      }
   }

public class AddressPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
   {
      public virtual string Street { get; set; }
      public virtual string Street2 { get; set; }
      public virtual string City { get; set; }
      public virtual string CountyName { get; set; }
      public virtual NationRecord State { get; set; }
      public virtual string Zip { get; set; }
   }

   public class AddressPart : ContentPart<AddressPartRecord>
   {
      public string Street
      {
         get { return Record.Street; }
         set { Record.Street = value; }
      }

      public string Street2
      {
         get { return Record.Street2; }
         set { Record.Street2 = value; }
      }

      public string City
      {
         get { return Record.City; }
         set { Record.City = value; }
      }

      public string CountyName
      {
         get { return Record.CountyName; }
         set { Record.CountyName = value; }
      }

      public NationRecord State
      {
         get { return Record.State; }
         set { Record.State = value; }
      }

      public string Zip
      {
         get { return Record.Zip; }
         set { Record.Zip = value; }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a Content Type that contains both Parts (ie. named *Company*), if that is the case this should work:

```
var query = _contentManager.Query("Company").Where<AddressPartRecord>(x => x.Street == "query street");

var list = query.ToList();
```

The list contains the ContentItems filtered by street. Using .As() and .As() over the items of the list you get access to each part.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tweaked my query around as you suggested but I didn't get back any results.  I double checked my actual table data and there are 2 results in my test data which should have matched the query.